# ScrollView starts on left, needs to start in middle (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a scroll view in my app. It has three view controllers to swipe between. I want my app to start on the middle view controller so there is one view controller on the left of it and one on the right. Instead, my app starts with the view controller at the left. How can I get it to start in the middle? I may need a step-by-step since I am new to this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My design:
[image]

I want it to start on the orange viewcontroller

Comment: You need to set the scroll view's `contentOffset`.

Answer (score 5):

Just set your scrollview's `contentOffset.x` to the required point in your `viewDidLoad()`

Try adding this in your `viewDidLoad()`,

```
yourScrollView.contentOffset.x = view.frame.width
```